# Fill foreign key in database based on auto increment from other table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql2o

I have two tables. The first table patienten has an auto increment id.
One "patienten" has multiple "gebit". idPatient is the foreign key from the two tables.

patienten:

[image]

gebit:

[image]

Now i want to fill the "gebit" table but i keep getting errors.

My code:

```
public void addTandenToDatabase(int fdi, String voorstelling, String toestand) {
    String insertSql = "insert into gebit(fdi, voorstelling, toestand) values (:fdiVal, :voorstellingVal, :toestandVal)";
    try (Connection con = sql2o.open()) {
        con.setRollbackOnException(false);
        con.createQuery(insertSql)
                .addParameter("fdiVal", fdi)
                .addParameter("voorstellingVal", voorstelling)
                .addParameter("toestandVal", toestand)
                .executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

the error i get:

[image]

I tried a second method where i add a valu to idPatient in gebit:

```
public void addTandenToDatabase(int fdi, String voorstelling, String toestand) {
    String insertSql = "insert into gebit(idPatient, fdi, voorstelling, toestand) values (:idVal, :fdiVal, :voorstellingVal, :toestandVal)";
    try (Connection con = sql2o.open()) {
        con.setRollbackOnException(false);
        con.createQuery(insertSql)
                .addParameter("fdiVal", fdi)
                .addParameter("idVal", fdi)
                .addParameter("voorstellingVal", voorstelling)
                .addParameter("toestandVal", toestand)
                .executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

But that gives me this error:

```
Error in executeUpdate, Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`toondoesselaere`.`gebit`, CONSTRAINT `idPatient` FOREIGN KEY (`idPatient`) REFERENCES `patienten` (`idPatient`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: Does gebit has column called idVal?

Comment: No, a column idPatient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You break a `foreign key`, as `gebit.idPatient` `references` `patienten.idPatient` and you try to insert a record into `gebit` with an `idPatient` which has no matching `patienten.idPatient`.

You need to review the `idPatient` you want to `insert` and see if that is incorrect; if so fix the bug resulting mistaken `idPatient`.

Comment: How do I make it match?

Comment: You need to make sure that whenever you insert a record, all its foreign keys reference existent values in the table it references to.